# How do I handle Neighborhood defense when gang members spawn as fast as I can kill them?

Tags: saints-row-2

I recently picked *Saints Row 2* up again after a year or so away from it. I have a situation where the Ronin are attacking the neighborhood where Aisha's house is. I've tried going in and killing the lieutenants, but even with a full gang and all of the weapons, the Ronin literally spawn faster than I can kill them. In the space of shooting a gangster in the head, another two cars will pull up out of nowhere. I am playing with the Gentlemen of the Row mod with a few of the settings turned on, but I don't see anything in the settings that should be boosting the spawn rate of the gangs or enhancing their weapons.

Should I just ignore the neighborhood and move on to the main plot? Do more side-missions to pick up some sort of benefits to better battle them? Hack some game files to nerf the Ronin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention going after the lieutenants, but it's worth re-iterating: the *moment* the last marked enemy dies, the event is over and everyone else loses aggro.

Beyond that, a couple suggestions come to mind (just started another playthrough of SR2 w/ GotR):

- Bring all the homies you can. If nothing else, they'll draw some fire so you can concentrate on the targets.
- Choose your battle - you'll get mobbed as soon as you enter the district, but not *until* you enter. So find out where the bosses are and plan your approach accordingly. Bring a heavier vehicle, punch directly in, drop them ASAP.
- If you're feeling evil, grab yourself a Tornado attack helicopter and just kill 'em all from the air. (It's possible to get one of them fairly early, or likely via GotR cheat if you're just feeling the need to vent.)